# Add image to page onclick

Tags: image, button, onclick

I want a button to add an image to the current page on each click. For example, the first time you open the page, there is one picture. Then you click the button and the same picture appears on the page and now you have two same pictures. Then you keep on pressing on the button and more and more same pictures appear. This is the code I tried that didn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function addimage() {<img src="http://bricksplayground.webs.com/brick.PNG" height="50" width="100">}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="addimage();">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably know that javascript can create html elements, but you cannot directly embed html inside javascript (they are two completely separate things with different grammars and keywords). So it's not valid to have a function that only contains html -- you need to create the elements you want, and then append them to the dom elements that you want them to. In this case, you create a new image and then append it to the body.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function addimage() { 
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = "http://bricksplayground.webs.com/brick.PNG"; 
          img.height = 50; 
          img.width = 100;

          //optionally set a css class on the image
          var class_name = "foo";
          img.setAttribute("class", class_name);

          document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="addimage();">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! But how do add an image class? I tried img.class but it didn't work.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to set a css class for an element. Hope this helps!

Comment: For some reason, after I added the class thing, the button didn't work. Am I supposed to replace the word "class" or "foo"? The class I am using is box2d, if that helps.

Comment: In the example code above, I'm setting a class named "foo" on the image added. I'll edit it to be a bit more clear. The setAttribute method takes two attributes -- the name of the atribute, and then the value.

Comment: Whoops, I referenced the wrong variable in the setAttribute call. My code was "image.setAttribute" when my variable is named "img". Sorry if that was what confused you.

Comment: It's not working. If I add anything to the code, it messes up and doesn't work.

Comment: Now, the class only works for the first image I add. As I said, I'm using the box2d.js.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6773/discussion-between-prplninja-and-tjarratt)

Answer (score -3):

All you're missing is a method to write the element on the page

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function addimage() {
      document.write('<img src="http://bricksplayground.webs.com/brick.PNG" height="50" width="100">')
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="addimage();">Click</button>
</body>
```

Comment: This will actually make the entire document a single image. You want to append to the body of the document, so you can continue adding images, not replace the button that was already there.