# Add image to screen on-click and allow it to be draggable/rotatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to create a sort of map builder where the user can select from a list of predefined objects, and upon clicking one of them, it will appear inside a frame with orientation options (dragging, rotating, resizing).

I don't understand how one can add functionality to an object that is undefined at the page's run time.

I have found a lot of good examples demonstrating how to use Jquery UI as well as adding an image to the screen onclick, but have never seen the two married together.

Here is a good example of the add onclick feature: [Add image to page onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886248/add-image-to-page-onclick)

(Orientation on click examples are quite numerous)

Here is the code I liked from the link (from tjarratt), so if someone could help me branch off from here that would be easiest.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function addimage() { 
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = "http://bricksplayground.webs.com/brick.PNG"; 
          img.height = 50; 
          img.width = 100;

          //optionally set a css class on the image
          var class_name = "foo";
          img.setAttribute("class", class_name);

          document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="addimage();">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is too broad, I recommend reposting it in multiple parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that may help you out. Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  function addImage(u, c, t) {
    /***
    Input: URL, Class, Target Object
    Output: jQuery Object of IMG element
    ***/
    if (u == undefined) {
      u = "https://bricksplayground.webs.com/brick.PNG";
    }
    if (c == undefined) {
      c == "";
    }
    if (t == undefined) {
      t = $("#zone");
    }
    var img = $("<img>", {
      src: u,
      class: c,
    }).css({
      width: "50px",
      height: "100px"
    });
    img.appendTo(t);
    return img;
  }

  function makeDrag(o) {
    /***
    Input: jQuery Object
    Output: null
    ***/
    o.draggable({
      containment: "parent"
    });
  }

  $("#add-object").click(function() {
    makeDrag(addImage("https://png.pngtree.com/png_detail/20181008/red-brick-wall-png-clipart_1564742.png", "foo"));
  });
});
```

```css
#zone {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="add-object">Add Object</button>
<div id="zone"></div>
```

When 'Add Object' is clicked, an Image element is created with specific attributes. I added some defaults so if you call, `addImage()`, it will still add an image. You can also specify your own URL, Class, and Target Object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So how would I pass a different URL to addImage() if we are just selecting all ID's of add-object to call the function?

Comment: @MikasThane I don't exactly understand the question. In your example, you created an image element and then you created a class. I don't see anything about an ID.

Comment: I figured it out, the your functions just needed to be made global by removing the overarching void function wrapper. Thanks so much!

Comment: I need to append the image to the same spot on the page every single time. Upon multiple appends, it always places the images next to the previous image and this causes problems. How could I go about appending images to the same origin point inside a div regardless of other images that are there?

Comment: @MikasThane I would advise using CSS and set an absolute position via `top` and `left` or make use of `.position()` in jQuery UI.